Tomcat 9.x: Alias name does not identify a key entry for Windows-MY keystore (Windows Sever 2019)
Running..

Servlet/WS: Apache Tomcat 9.0.80
OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard
Java: OpenJDK 16.0.2 (64-bit, mixed mode, sharing)

I have a PFX file containing the private and public key (cert). It also contains the intermediary cert and the root cert. The PFX file is password-protected. It was created with keytool. The key alias is (i.e. mycertalias). I imported the private key and cert into the Windows Store via the cert manager (Local Computer) (certlm.msc). Under Personal\Certificates. Friendly Name of the cert reads the same as the key alias. I then popped open server.xml in Tomcat and configured the connector:
<Connector 
        port="443"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="1500"
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        clientAuth="false"
        sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        keyAlias=""
        keystoreFile=""
        keystoreType="Windows-MY"
        keystorePass=""
        truststoreFile=""
        truststoreType="Windows-ROOT"
        truststorePass=""
        enableLookups="true"
    />

I configured Tomcat to debug all, via Java Option: -Djavax.net.debug=all.
Tomcat runs under the Local System account.
The exception thrown refers to Alias name [mycertalias] does not identify a key entry:
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector["https-jsse-nio-443"]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1011)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:554)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1040)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [mycertalias] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:236)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1324)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1337)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1009)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [mycertalias] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:343)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:253)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)

I checked the PFX file again and again. The key alias is a private key entry, via keytool. I exported the private key and cert from the Windows store and confirmed with keytool the key alias matches what I originally imported into said store, which, in this case, is "mycertalias". I even imported the private key and cert into the Tomcat service account Cert snap-in, in case Tomcat is looking there instead of the computer account. Didn't make a difference.
I know it's finding the Windows store. The question is does Windows-MY refer to the same cert store or has the name of the store changed to something else for newer Windows OS releases and I need to use that instead?
I tried Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE but Tomcat reports no such store exists. So, that's not it. Either Windows-MY refers to a different Windows store or, for some odd reason, it's not able to find the cert entry, even though the cert has been imported with the proper key alias. I've tried setting in the server.xml: keyAlias="", removing the keyAlias, keyAlias=1, and even keyAlias="Tomcat". Nothing works. I tried setting keyAlias to the Common Name of the cert. Doesn't work. I don't know what else I can do other than to start from scratch and re-create the PFX file.
Any ideas what may be the culprit here?

This seems relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71083342/tomcat-unable-to-access-cert-in-windows-cert-store

Is the account you're using to load the cert the same one Tomcat runs under?

The account I'm using to load the PFX (private key and cert) into the Windows cert store is an admin account. The Tomcat windows service is running under the Local System account. Perhaps I may need to update the Tomcat service to run under a service account and then add the cert to that service account's cert store? Based on the article you referenced, that may be what I have to do. Not sure what else to try at this point.

Windows services have a separate My/Personal store. You should be able to select it by running mmc, loading certificates and selecting service when prompted.

But whatever account Tomcat is running as does seem to be able to see the cert, assuming the cert and key are loaded into only one Windows key store.

I had tried that before, opening the Tomcat service under Certificates -> Service Account, and adding the cert there. Made no difference, unfortunately.  The Tomcat service is running as a Windows service, yes, under the Local System account, fwiw. I just tried re-creating the PFX file from the private key and key using openSSL and importing that into the Windows cert store. It created key alias of 1. Still did not work.. I tried both computer account and Tomcat service account. The only thing I didn't try yet is "My user account" which may be the next step perhaps.

From the feedback here and the SO question referenced earlier, I got it to work. I created a new service user and updated the Tomcat service to run under said service user. It was Local System user prior. Then I imported the PFX file as the service user (run as from CLI and run mmc). Restarted Tomcat and it worked. The Local System user does not have access to the Windows-MY store, apparently. OK, so what store represents the computer account cert store (certlm.msc)? Couldn't I just update the server.xml to that store? There must be something in the Registry that has the answer here.

Reading the JDK bug tracker, it would appear this was fixed in JDK 19, where Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE and Windows-ROOT-LOCALMACHINE were added (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6782021). The server I have is on JDK 16, which explains why those key stores didn't work for me. As such, another option might be upgrading to JDK 19 or later, set the keystore to Windows-MY-LOCALMACHINE, and then run Tomcat service under the Local System account and see if it finds the cert/private key.
